# No rule to make target 'QtCharts/QChartView>', needed by 'ui_display.h'. Stop

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I'm working with Qt 5.12.5 and add the plugin QtCharts::QChartView in Qt Designer. But when I compile project, the error below appear:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'QtCharts/QChartView>', needed by 'ui_display.h'.  Stop.
```

It seems like qt cannot compile module QtCharts/QChartView. Any suggestion?

I already

- installed Qt Charts and Qt Data Visualization by using Qt Maintainer
- add `QT += charts` in .pro file

Comment: If you copied the error message correctly my guess is you have a typo in your #include statement perhaps `#include "QtCharts/QChartView>"`

Comment: ui_display.h is a generated file by Qt Designer from display.ui so there is nothing I can do with the include. But I check the ui_display.h too (there is no type)